# Meteor cordova on Android building app

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to test my app on my phone. I did this:

```
meteor build <bundle path> --server <host>:<port>
```

I took the `aligned.apk` from the build folder and put it on my phone but it gave an error when I tried to install.

I tried `brew install android-sdk` and downloaded the latest apk, but that still didn't work.

I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Please help.

Comment: What is exact error you are getting? Please try post same in question

Comment: @adjuke the error is "x app not installed" this occurs even with a "Welcome to meteor" app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, dug a little deeper, here's what worked for me. See here for android:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store

specifically:

```
keytool -genkey -alias your-app-name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

cd ~/build-output-directory/android/
jarsigner -digestalg SHA1 unaligned.apk your-app-name

~/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/build-tools/20.0.0/zipalign 4 unaligned.apk production.apk
```

Then install the "production.apk" to your device.

Comment: For all that still have problems: I had to change the hash algorithm to `-sigalc MD5withRSA`. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29562922/3223028.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this?

https://www.meteor.com/try/7

For iOS you need to install Xcode which is about 2GB ([XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12))

1. meteor install-sdk ios
2. meteor add-platform ios
3. meteor run ios (Simulator) or
4. meteor run ios-device (Device) or
5. meteor run ios-device --mobile-server my_app_name.meteor.com

Try to read upon this:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

and this:
http://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-mobile-development-meteor/

Comment: yup, i'm having problems with the apk after the building the app

Comment: @ShinonChan were u able to get anything to work? I have the same problem. Getting a little frustrated how all the docs and tutorials on Meteor focus on the simulator, with no discussion on actually building and installing