# Meteor android build says "Application not installed"

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, phonegap-build

I am doing android app in meteor. Its in development stage. I just tried to build apk for testing purpose. But when I try to install apk file, device says "Application not installed". I tried the following steps.

```
meteor build ../build --server 192.168.0.5:3000
```

The above command generate `unaligned.apk` file in android directory and `CordovaApp-release-unsigned.apk` in android/project/ant-build directory. Both apk says "Application not installed". So I add following lines

```
App.info({
  name: 'My App',
  description: 'An Android app built with Meteor',
  version: '0.0.1'
});
```

in `mobile-config.js` in app root directory. But Again I got the same issue "Application not installed".

Is anything wrong in my steps? Why APK is not installed? How to build right apk with meteor?

Comment: if you still have problems maybe my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29562922/3223028 helps.

Comment: @Miriam thanks post in answer field Let me accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me answer my question. It works fine for me.

Build APK by

```
meteor build ~/build-output-directory \
    --server=your-desired-app-hostname.meteor.com
```

Now you can sign your app by

```
keytool -genkey -alias your-app-name -keyalg RSA \
    -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

cd ~/build-output-directory/android/
jarsigner -digestalg SHA1 unaligned.apk your-app-name
```

After signed I can able to install and share my apk file. More detail from [meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a bug in meteor. You should sign in your application.
Please, check the following thread:
[Meteor cordova on Android building app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294258/meteor-cordova-on-android-building-app)

Answer (score 0):

I see there is an accepted answer but maybe anyone with my problem will find this useful:

I had the same "App not Installed" error even though I was 100% sure that app is signed and zipalined. Then I tried to install the app through adb:

```
$ adb install my_app.apk
Error: [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Then I realised that probably my app was not deleted properly from my phone so I uninstalled it with adb (since I was unable to uninstal using the phone GUI) and it worked :)

```
$adb uninstall com.my_app.id
```

Hope this helps someone.